# Proving $V(f)$ is finite when $f$ is non-constant

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

My problem asks me to show that if $f$ is non-constant, then $\mathbf{V}(f)$ is finite. Assume that $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.

If $f$ was an ideal, this would be straightforward; however, $f$ is merely a polynomial described above. I suppose by "non-constant" the prompt means "a polynomial with max degree greater than or equal to $1$."

I tried proving this through the contrapositive: if $\mathbf{V}(f)$ is infinite, then $f$ must be constant.  $\mathbf{V}(f)$ is infinite implies that every point in the affine space must be a zero; if every point is a zero, then $f(x)=0$, which is a constant function.

Is this logic valid? Am I missing something fundamental?

The reason I am doubting myself is the following: if $f=c$ where $c ≠ 0$, wouldn't  $\mathbf{V}(c)= \emptyset$? I'm not sure that $\emptyset$ and infinity is the same.

Thanks in advance for any useful clarification/hints.

Comment: Hmm. There are functions that have infinitely many zeros without being constants. Sine comes to mind. Of course, sine is not a polynomial. So something special about polynomials has to play a role here. Looks like I'm not buying your logic. At least not wholesale.

Comment: Why do you think that it would be easier, if $f$ were an ideal? Do you know that $V(f)$ and $V(J)$ are equal, when $J$ is the ideal generated by $f$? So if you can do it for ideals...

Answer (score 4):

I assume you mean $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, not $f \in \mathbb{C}[x, y]$, because otherwise $V(f)$ is a curve consisting of infinitely many points for any nonconstant polynomial $f$.

Now, if $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$, you have the following:

- If $f = 0$ then $V(f) = \mathbb{A}^1$.
- If $f$ is a nonzero constant function, then $V(f)$ is empty.
- Otherwise, $V(f)$ consists of finitely many points.

The contrapositive of "$f$ non-constant implies $V(f)$ finite" is "$V(f)$ infinite implies $f$ is constant."  In particular, it does *not* include the statement that $V(f)$ is infinite *whenever* $f$ is constant.

Now, as for your argument, it is true that $V(f)$ infinite implies that every point of $\mathbb{A}^1$ is a zero of $f$, but I'm not convinced from what you've written that you understand why.  Why can't I have some polynomial with zeroes at 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... but nowhere else?

Comment: I made the appropriate edit for f∈ℂ[x]- thanks. I also understand the distinction in the contrapositive. As for my argument being consistent, I guess I'm not sure why you ask that question at the end; perhaps you could extrapolate? Thanks for your help, btw!

Comment: Well, you say that if a polynomial vanishes at infinitely many points, then it vanishes at *every* point.  But why?  Why can't I have a polynomial vanishing at infinitely many points, and also not vanishing at infinitely many other points, like the function $\sin(x)$ does?

Comment: good question. I don't know. My understanding is that $\sin(x)$ isn't a polynomial? The only polynomial that comes to my mind that contains infinitely many zeros is $f(x)=0$.  If you have a counter example, I'd love to hear it

Comment: Of course there is no counterexample, or else the result wouldn't be true.  But you need to *prove* that there's no nonzero polynomial with infinitely many zeroes.  How could you do that?

Comment: Can you have a polynomial with an infinite amount of terms? Even if you could, you'd need to account for each irrational number, which we know isn't possible

Comment: A polynomial, by definition, has finitely many terms.

Comment: Very good- I'm on the same page. The only way to have a "zero" in the polynomial is if you could factor out (x-a), where f(a)=0. Correct?

Comment: Right, so it seems like you're approaching the idea that a polynomial of degree $d$ has at most $d$ distinct zeroes, which is the step that you need to make your proof work.

Comment: I assumed that, I guess, but I will state it to make the proof complete. Thanks!